# Returning a multidimensional array of variable size in c

Tags: c, multidimensional-array

*I have found a piece of code in the book understanding pointers in c
which is used to return pointers to 2 and 3 dimensional arrays of fixed size*

```
#define ROW 3
#define COL 4
#define SET 2

int (*fun1())[ROW][COL];
int (*fun2())[SET][ROW][COL];
```

**Here fun1 and fun2 are the functions which returns the pointer to a 2d array and 3d array respectively where the arrays are of fixed sizes**

**Is there any possibility for returning a pointer to a multidimensional array of variable size in c language ???**

*Please help me and thanks in advance .*

Comment: If you could return a multidimensional array of a variable size, the call must be able to retrieve the number of items for each dimensions. You can return a pointer that originally points to a n-dim array. But the caller gets only the pointer to one (first) item and has no chance to get info about dimensions. Therefore your desire can't be satisfied with such a pointer.

Comment: ok for suppose consider returning is possible. What would be a function prototype for such a function ??.I just want to know function prototype